# Show One To Many Relation Data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, one-to-many

I'm facing a problem with displaying records using CodeIgniter. I've done this using pure PHP code but I'm quite confused how can I do it using CodeIgniter.

```
Doctor         Doctor Specialty     
Rashid         Cardiology, Gastroenterology , Neurology
```

**Controller code:**

```
public function appointmentSixStats(){

  $this->load->view('admin/dashboard/appointment-stats-doctor',$this->data);
}
```

**My table structure:**

- `tbl_doctor`
- `tbl_specialty`          (Contain all the specialties)
- `tbl_doctor_specialty`   (Contain all the doctor assign specialties)
- `tbl_appointment`     (Contain all the doctor appointment)

**The problem:**

- How can I pass the data to the views?
- How can I loop through the data as it comes from 1 to many relations?

I'm willing to show each doctor record as comma-separated values along with their specialties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**GROUP_CONCAT(expr)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) how ever it is not recommended because of character length restriction of default set to 1024 character but it can be increased

```
$sql="SELECT d.* ,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.title) specialities,
GROUP_CONCAT(a.title) appointments
FROM  tbl_doctor d
JOIN tbl_doctor_specialty ds ON (d.id = ds.doctor_id)
JOIN tbl_specialty  s ON (s.id = ds.speciality.id)
JOIN tbl_appointment  a ON (a.doctor_id =d.id)
GROUP BY d.id";
$result=$this->db->query($sql);
return $result->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from query itself.

Try this code.

```
    $this->db->select('d.name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.specialty SEPARATOR ",") as doc_specialty'); 
    $this->db->from('tbl_doctor d');   
    $this->db->join('tbl_doctor_specialty ds', 'd.id = ds.doctor_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_specialty s', 's.id = ds.specialty_id');
    $this->db->group_by("d.id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Using aggregate functions its recommended to use `GROUP BY` otherwise it will result in a single row not results per group [*GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Sorry i missed to add that line. Thanks :-)